# ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

First,my Kafka's gav is org.apache.kafka || kafka_2.11  || 0.9.0.0,my spark-streaming's gav is org.apache.spark  || spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 || 2.2.0

I meet this error fellow the The official website's guides,I search some answers about this error.that tell me is the version cases,So I change my Kafka's version
to 0.8.2.0,the problem is solved.So I catn't under stand is, why I meet this problem under the guides from the office website.Is the office website error?

please do me a favor.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.
My scala-library version is 2.10.x,but the spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 is dependence the 2.11.x,so I change the spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 to spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.10.The problem is solved。